Page not found (404) en Django 5.1
Estoy Usando Django 5.1 estoy queriendo actualizar los datos de mi formulario pero me sale el mensaje de error Page not found (404)

el codigo
urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from tareas import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('', views.inicio, name='inicio'),
   path('registrar/', views.registrar, name='registrar'),
   path('tareas/', views.tareas, name='tareas'),
   path('tareas/crear/', views.crear_tarea, name='crear_tarea'),
   path('tareas/<int:tarea_id>/', views.detalle_tarea, name='detalle_tarea'),
]

views.py
def detalle_tarea(request, tarea_id):
if request.method == 'GET':
    tarea = get_object_or_404(Tarea, pk=tarea_id)
    form = TareaForm(instance=tarea)
    return render(request, 'tarea_detalles.html', 
                {'tarea': tarea, 'form': form})
else:
    tarea = get_object_or_404(Tarea, pk=tarea_id)
    form = TareaForm(request.POST, instance=tarea)
    form.save()
    return redirect('tareas')


talvez tu problema esta en los templates, al mandar a llamar alguna de las direcciones del path, creo que definiste el atributo method = "post" y en la funcion estas pidiendo que sea un GET
